# ajax save in database without having foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, foreign-keys

I have a form for users to sign up. This form has a file input which will upload images in a directory in server by ajax instantly as user selects a file. There's also a button which will submit the form and saves user info in `user` table in database.

Each user can have multiple images. Ajax also save address of images in `photos` table when file uploads. this table has `user_id` column. but since the `user_id` will be generated when submit button is hit and user is not registered yet, I can't fill `user_id` column in `photos` table. The id of user is generated when whole form is submitted.

so should I update `photos` table when form submits by adding id of user to `user_id` column?
or I must save photos with ajax in `temporary_photos` table and then when submit is hit save them in main photos table and delete them from temporary table?

or is there another approach?

what if user uploads files, but closes the window without hitting submit button? how I find out the window is close and registration is canceled so i will delete images?

Comment: what have you tied so far?

Comment: Save the photos in a temp place. Move to the real place and add DB row on submit, is what I would probably do.

Comment: It's better don't let them upload a photo before register.

Comment: at first I wanted to upload multiple files and preview them by only one input. so I decided to upload the file instantly by ajax. now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to solve a problem that you created. If `user_id` is a dependency for the photo to be saved, let the user be saved first.If you do it the other way , it you will over complicate the workflow.

So, i suggest you register the user first, save the user id in session (or log the user in) and then upload the photo.

If you must do it together, then let the ajax request register the user and then save the photo and save the `user_id` in a session variable. Next time you upload a photo you could get the user from session variable and save the photo.

```
function savePhoto(Request $input){
   if(Session::has('user_id'){
     $user = User::find(Session::get('user_id'));
   }
   else{
     $user = User::create($input->all());
   }

   $user->photo->save($input->all());
 }
```

Comment: I actually want to know if there's any solution before starting over. if I create a user by ajax request, it's possible user close the window before hitting register. so I'll have tones of unregistered users in database over time.

Comment: Ideally, you should only store photos and other information of only registered users. You could submit the photos and the registration details only after the user clicks register, so you dont have to worry when users back off.

If you must get the photos first, then do register the user and create a field called `status` in user table and assign it to `temp` while uploading photos and change it to `registered` after user registers. And you could clear all the `temp` entries from a cron job. but again this is complicating the workflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this is the best answer. I found an example of what I had in mind in [this website](http://www.sheypoor.com/listing/new) , but it's in persian. It's a website for people to put advertisement online, when you click the + button on left column, it sends the image to server without registering any ad or user

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way-

Since an user can have multiple images that means the relation is one to many between. So better if you use a `images` table.

Table: Images

Column(s): `id, user_id, image, uploaded_at`

Make `user_id` field is nullable and `image` column will save the name of uploaded images. Upon successful uploading and adding iamges record to database save last inserted ids in a session array. Once the user submit the form, create a record to user table, grab the last insert it, check if there are any data in session array, if found, loop through the array and select those images record by id and update `user_id` field. This will solve your problem.

You also asked for a way to delete images for which users didn't submit the form. To do this, you can run a cronjob/laravel task schedular. A script that will remove images and delete records for those images which were uploaded 5 mins (for example) ago and `user_id` is still null.